How to process the entire WebADI file at once rather than processing each line at a time
WebADI functionality usually processes one line at a time. However, due to some validations in the packages that I've used for WebADI (I have also called a concurrent program thrrough the package) , I need the WebADI to process all the data at once i.e. the package & concurrent program call should only happen once.
Should I use some "bulk load" type function and then process it?
However, I am not aware if bulk load will be able to store data from WebADI all at once.
Thanks!

I’m not sure that web ADI can do bulk processing.  Is there a bulk interface table associated with this functionality?   If so, you might want to leverage that.

I was able to do bulk processing with the "Importer" but in that case I am not able to validate now. The package used in importer does not give error in the WebADI. Only the package from the Interface gives error to user. And even if one record fails, all other records are not processed by the importer.
